# Select a different .cabal file?

Tags: haskell, cabal

To develop multiple cabal components simultaneously I have a separate cabal file that lumps these all into a single component. Is there a way to call `cabal repl` such that that other "development" cabal file is used?

There indeed is a `--cabal-file` option, but that doesn't appear to work, e.g calling `cabal repl --cabal-file package.cabal.dev package` still uses `package.cabal` instead of `package.cabal.dev`.

Comment: If what you say is true, then that seems like a bug worth (minimizing and) reporting.

Comment: You might also want to subscribe to [this feature request issue](https://github.com/haskell/cabal/issues/8238).